# Will deleted mails open in Ipad?

Tags: ipad, gmail

I have sent a mail to my friend's Gmail account. He is using Gmail in Apple Ipad 4th generation. Now i came to know that his ipad is not with him. So i opened his Gmail in PC and deleted the mail in his inbox. Now, will the sent mail be available on his ipad? (IPad is connected to internet when the mail was sent).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It will depend on the sync interval of the iPad. The likely outcome is no.